# Nodejs: I get "FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose"-error when I try to read a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, express

I am trying to append objects to JSON files.

For example, I have JSON files like:

```
{
    "_1": {
        "watch" : "undefined"
    },
    "_2": {
        "watch" : "undefined"
    }
}
```

and that is the part of my app.js that doesn't work:

```
app.post('/add2', (req, res) => {
    storeAt = path.join(__dirname + '/json/' + req.body.addTo + '.json');

    id = req.body.id;
    i = req.body.i;

    fs.readFile(storeAt, (err, data) => {
        console.log("data: " + data);
        var temp = JSON.parse(data);
        temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length - 2);
        temp += ',\n\t"_' + i + '": {\n\t\t"watch" : "' + id + '"\n\t}\n}';

        fs.writeFile(storeAt, JSON.stringify(temp));

});
```

So basically I want to read the file and save it in a variable, then delete the last to characters, add something new to it and save it.

The `console.log("data : + data);` works just fine; the content of the JSON file is displayed on the console. But the problem is in the line with the `.substring`. I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: temp.substring is not a function
at fs.readFile (C:\...\app.js:56:21)
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:442:3)
```

I couldn't find any help on the internet and I don't really understand the TypeError. Can anyone help?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` will return an object rather than a string, that's the reason substring is not defined.

Maybe you can just work with the parsed object and add the value from there, and later just use `JSON.stringify`. Modifying JSON manually can be a pain

Comment: Thank you for your help Omar, I solved my problem: I removed the `JSON.parse` line and the `JSON.stringify` command in my code:
`fs.readFile(storeAt, 'utf8', (err, fileContents) => {
        // Edit fileContents
        fs.writeFile(storeAt, fileContents, err => { });`