# Why doesn't the downloaded drive spreadsheet contain any data even with mimeType set?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am using a combination of the examples provided to download a document to my filesystem, in the future directly to the server but that's the next step.
The code runs without errors but the worksheet created has 0 bytes and cannot be opened. Any ideas please? The documentation is giving me analysis paralysis.

I have consulted countless github posts and questions here but nothing seems to stick.

```
            const fs = require('fs');
            const readline = require('readline');
            const {google} = require('googleapis');

            // If modifying these scopes, delete credentials.json.
            const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
            const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

            /**
             * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
             * given callback function.
             * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
             * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
             */
            function authorize(credentials, callback) {
                const {
                    client_secret,
                    client_id,
                    redirect_uris
                } = credentials.installed;
                const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

                // Check if we have previously stored a token.
                fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
                    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
                    callback(oAuth2Client);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
             * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
             * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
             */
            function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
                const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                    access_type: 'offline',
                    scope: SCOPES,
                });
                console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
                const rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: process.stdin,
                    output: process.stdout,
                });
                rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
                    rl.close();
                    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                        if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                        // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                            if (err) console.error(err);
                            console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
                        });
                        callback(oAuth2Client);
                    });
                });
            }


            // Load client secrets from a local file.
            fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
                authorize(JSON.parse(content), grabFileFromDrive);
            });

            function grabFileFromDrive(auth) {
                const drive = google.drive({
                    version: 'v3',
                    auth
                });
                var fileId = '<FILEIDHERE>';
                var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/feedback-list.xlsx');
                drive.files.export({
                    fileId: fileId,
                    mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                }, {
                    responseType: 'stream'
                }), function(err, res){
                res.data
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log('Done');
                })
                .on('error', err => {
                    console.log('Error', err);
                })
                .pipe(dest);
                console.log(res);}
            }
```

The document downloaded is corrupt/incorrectly formatted and has a 0 size value, how can I get a working excel sheet downloaded to my directory?

UPDATE: I have added working code below, I think the issue was token related and not being able to view the error produced within the downloaded document alerting me to insufficient scopes, either that or the response function wasn't in the right place, rebuilt it all again from documentation and a tutorial and somehow this works now. Hope it helps

```
            const fs = require('fs');
            const readline = require('readline');
            const {
                google
            } = require('googleapis');

            // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
            const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

            const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

            // Load client secrets from a local file.
            fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
                authorize(JSON.parse(content), downloadDriveFile);
            });

              function authorize(credentials, callback) {
                const {
                    client_secret,
                    client_id,
                    redirect_uris
                } = credentials.installed;
                const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

                // Check if we have previously stored a token.
                fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
                    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
                    callback(oAuth2Client);
                });
            }

            function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
                const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                    access_type: 'offline',
                    scope: SCOPES,
                });
                console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
                const rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: process.stdin,
                    output: process.stdout,
                });
                rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
                    rl.close();
                    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                        if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
                        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                        // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                            if (err) console.error(err);
                            console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
                        });
                        callback(oAuth2Client);
                    });
                });
            }

            function downloadDriveFile(auth) {
                const drive = google.drive({
                    version: 'v3',
                    auth
                });
                var fileId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
                var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/feedback.csv');
                // example code here
                drive.files.export({
                        fileId: fileId,
                        mimeType: 'text/csv'
                        // excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                    }, {
                        responseType: 'stream'
                    },
                    function (err, res) {
                        res.data
                            .on('end', () => {
                                console.log('Done');
                            })
                            .on('error', err => {
                                console.log('Error', err);
                            })
                            .pipe(dest);
                    })
                ///
            }
```

Comment: try some alternative export formats (eg. text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel) and see what that gives.

Comment: Thank you, I did try few combos now again, including changing the extension of the out file for testing but each applicable kind creates downloads the sheet but its empty/corrupt, I even tried a few of MS other types but nada. Could it be a permission thing?

Comment: And to be safe I have also created a new spreadsheet in sheets and copied the data over to try that but no luck either.

Comment: If I change the type to application/vnd.ms-excel I get (node:1136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [object Object]

Comment: I saw this thread about JSON, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710912/nodejs-i-get-fsreqwrap-readfileafterclose-error-when-i-try-to-read-a-json-fil, I also tried removing the JSON references but that threw an error with authentication. I havent been able to get the 'res' or 'dest' variables to print so it looks like there is no data coming in yet and hence the empty file being created without any data. Any suggestions how to test this further please?

Comment: ok I solved it myself, somehow, I think that after changing scopes I didn't get a new token although I am certain I tried that many times too, also installed to     "googleapis": "^27.0.0", which I 'think' allowed me to get the error in a csv file which led me to the scopes/token issue. I can now download the files. I will post my working update above.